# Android: Apply a blur effect (BlurMaskFilter) on a View

Tags: android, view, blur

Is it possible to apply a blur effect (BlurMaskFilter) on a View without using a bitmap screenshot of the View ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this library - [BlurringView](https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur/) by 500px. They describe the design process in a blog post [here](http://developers.500px.com/2015/03/17/a-blurring-view-for-android.html). The BlurringView blurs any view that is beneath it. They use `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` from the `android.support.renderscript` library to achieve this effect.

I suppose OP would no longer need it, but this answer might be useful for someone else.